# Copy Azure Queue messages to another storage account

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues, azure-storage-account

We have a Queue created in storage account. an external system is creating messages in the Queue.

So I need to process the messages for 2 environments (say PROD and Stage). So I have a Queue trigger available in both environments but the messages available in only one Queue.

If we copy the messages to another Queue also, the Queue trigger will be executed in both environments.

Is it possible to copy messages from one Queue to another Queue or how it can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to copy messages from one Queue to another Queue or how
> it can be done?

Natively Azure Storage does not support copying messages from one queue to another. What you will have to do is create a new message based on the contents/properties of an existing message.

You can create the message in another queue when you are processing the message in your queue trigger.

However a better way to handle this is to make use of `Azure Service Bus Topics and Subscriptions`. In this case you will send a single message to a `Service Bus Topic` and create 2 Subscriptions in that Topic. The message will be sent to both Subscriptions. Then you can have two Functions each of which is listening to one of the Subscriptions.

That way you do not have to worry about manually copying the message to another Queue.